# IdentityServer4 with Windows/AD authentication not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I created a new project for IdentityServer4 and included the QuickUI. Then I following the link http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html to add the Windows Authentication.

**startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) { app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

However, the external login button still isn't shown in the page https://localhost:44378/Account/Login. I found that the `DisplayName` of `await _schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync()` is null and the `schema.Name` is `idsrv.external` instead of `Windows` (`AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName`).

**AccountController.cs**

*`private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)`*

```
var schemes = await _schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();

var providers = schemes
    .Where(x => x.DisplayName != null || // schemes.DisplayName is null
                (x.Name.Equals(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName, // "idsrv.external" != "Windows"
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    )
    .Select(x => new ExternalProvider
    {
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        AuthenticationScheme = x.Name
    }).ToList();
```

How to fix the problem?

BTW, I only need to authenticate against Windows/AD so I don't need to have the external buttons. How to change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to disable "Anonymous Authentication" and enable "Windows Authentication".

Answer (score 0):

When using Kestrel, you must use the IIS integration:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

Changes in ConfigureServices.

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis => 
{  
  iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
  iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});
```

You must enable Windows and anonymous authentication (IIS or IISExpress)

**Note**: If you are using VisualStudio and IISExpress, please run Visual Studio as 'Administrator'.

For detailed info: Refer this Link: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/windows.html